# Error while executing the “npm install” command in ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, npm-install, node-gyp

I have been trying to install and run my first hyperledger fabric application (http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html) but have been encountering the following issue everytime I run the "npm install" command.
 Please let me know what is the solution to resolve this issue.

The error is as follows:

[image: see image]

I have tried deleted .node-gyp, .npmrc folder from $HOME and restarting the computer.Nothing helped.

Answer (score 2):

Faced a similar issue in Centos 7 and resolved by installing the development tools..

To compile and install native addons from npm you need to install the development tools.

Running the following commands will resolve your issue;

> sudo apt install gcc g++ make
>
> npm install

Answer (score 0):

node-gyp has dependency on ms visual basic redistributable. You have to check that relation and install. Hope you have done that.

Answer (score 0):

Change the python version to 2.7. Then run

```
npm install -g --production windows-build-tools
```

as administrator.